# libtool on windows requires absolute path, when I'm already giving it an absolute path

Tags: c++, windows, libtool

I'm trying to compile libjpeg on windows, which uses libtool as part of it's process.

Whenever i tried to make install, libtool would complain about absolute paths, despise the fact that I was giving it an absolute path

```
$ ../configure --enable-shared --enable-static --prefix D:/hernan/programacion/libjpeg/install
$ make install
(bunch of unrelated descriptions)
./libtool --mode=install /bin/install -c libjpeg.la D:/hernan/programacion/libjpeg/install/lib/libjpeg.la
libtool: install: `D:/hernan/programacion/libjpeg/install/lib' must be an absolute directory name
Try `libtool --help --mode=install' for more information.
```

I'm using mingw shell, since ./configure never works on cmd

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution for this is rather silly.

While the link and compile modes interpret correctly my path, the install mode that depends on libtool doesn't. You have to change the driver part of the prefix erasing the : and encasing it between /
So in my case it ended up being

```
$ ../configure --enable-static --enable-shared --prefix /d/hernan/programacion/libjpeg/install
```